# Java games applet not connecting to Yahoo

Tags: java

I am trying to play a Y! game which use a java applet.  The applet displays the message:

Alert.
Unable to connect to server.
One of four things could have caused this:
1) You are behind a firewall.
2) You are not connected to the internet.
3) The games server is down.
4) You have a stale page in your cache.

I have added an exception to the Windows firewall for java.exe.
I am obviously connected to the Internet okay.
The games server is not down when I am at home.  I doubt it is down when I am at work.  I have never successfully loaded this page before, so I doubt I have a stale page in cache.

Could it be the corporate firewall?  Nothing else in my web browser has been blocked before.  Maybe the java applet connects on a different port to the browser.

What should I test?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Java is up-to-date:  http://www.java.com/

Clear your cache (easier than updating software, usually) just in case it is a corrupt cache (not uncommon with some web browsers), and if that doesn't work you can also try clearing your cookies (if possible, for that site only).

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I cleared the cache, and reinstalled the latest version of Java, but the issue remains.  I have sure it has something to do with the corporate firewall.